# RSA Machine Keys folder is empty - Windows 10

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, encryption

I am trying to test the aspnet_regiis.exe encryption function for a WPF app using the default RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider.  The encryption command runs successfully, and I can see the connection string section is encrypted; however, the application crashes at startup.  It works fine without the encryption.  I have added proper permissions to the machine keys folder as well as the key container, but I also noticed this folder is empty.  The path is: C:\Windows\System32\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys

I have also tried exporting from my dev machine and importing the keys on a separate machine (still giving the proper permissions).  No matter what I try, the machine keys folder is empty and the app fails to launch.

My questions are:

Shouldn't my imported keys be showing up in the machine keys folder, and given the appropriate permissions, shouldn't the configuration section be decrypted at runtime allowing the app to work as expected?

I have checked the windows event logs and found the error(s) which I will share along with the configuration file if necessary.

I always appreciate any tips or advice, and appreciate your time.

Side note - I know this isn't the most secure security practice.

-Thank you

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 10 the folder has changed:
Now you will find the MachineKeys Folder on this location:

> C:\Users\All Users\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys

The other folder is still there, but it is empty.

Comment: Do you have a link to the information, that it changed?

Comment: On my Windows 10 there is a junction, so C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys as same as C:\Users\All Users\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10 if you cannot see folder All Users, Find folder on this location

> C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys